# hover zoom & click effect on CSS background-image - Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, click, hover, background-image

**Scenario 1

I have a map with locations on it, once a location is hovered over i would like the icon to enlarge/grow and a div containing the name of the location to slide in from the side, in the div below, then once the mouse-cursor leaves the icon area i would like the div and the name of the location to slide back (completely disappearing) and then return the location icon to its original size.

**Scenario 2

Once hovered over & then clicked i would like the icon to remain at its enlarged size displaying the actual address underneath the location name, until it or another icon has been selected / clicked.

I have made a start on the jsfiddle below but cant seem to get much further as i am fairly new at working with jquery:

http://jsfiddle.net/gavAusWeb/sCFX2/2/

A live example of what im trying to achieve can be found here towards the bottom right hand side of the page.

http://www.aviationgroundhandling.com.au/

Thanks in advance !! :)

ps. i am using a CMS so it has to be done with background-images, cheers ;)

Comment: @Marc Uberstein - hey mate, long time !! Nearly a year, here is a new one for ya, if you have the time of course, thanks!!

Comment: @ShankarSangoli - Pulling out all the old draw cards :P If you have time, check out this little 'query' of mine, thanks mate !!

Answer (score 0):

`zoom` is not what you think it is. In fact, `zoom` is a IE only "feature", that is often used to trigger `hasLayout` when bugs arise. It is NOT a feature to adjust the browser's or element's zoom.
For what you want to do, you can use css3 transitions, `scale` in particular. Or `SVG` could be an option too. Finally, less elegant you could use jQuery to animate an image *sprite* containing different frames.

Comment: Thanks for you reply !! hmm scale, but what about support for older browsers if you use that method..?